# How to declare runtime.LockOSThread() and runtime.UnlockOSThread()

Tags: go

I could not able to find how to declare [runtime.LockOSThread()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) and [runtime.UnlockOSThread()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#UnlockOSThread). I define it like [runtime.LockOSThread()] some code [runtime.UnlockOSThread()]. But it is giving error,undefined: runtime.LockOSThread and undefined: runtime.UnlockOSThread. Can anybody suggest me how to define it ? For more, I define it like,

```
Routine 1 {
runtime.LockOSThread()
do something
runtime.UnlockOSThread

}

main {
routine1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "runtime"

func routine() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    runtime.UnlockOSThread()
}

func main() {
    go routine()
}
```

Comment: Thanks peterSO. I am sorry because I am trying this code to execute on http://play.golang.org/ . That's why it is giving error. On my desktop, this code(and my example code also) running properly.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, refer to [the documentation](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/runtime/).

```
func LockOSThread()

LockOSThread wires the calling goroutine to its current operating system thread.
Until the calling goroutine exits or calls UnlockOSThread, it will always execute in
that thread, and no other goroutine can.

func UnlockOSThread()

UnlockOSThread unwires the calling goroutine from its fixed operating system thread.
If the calling goroutine has not called LockOSThread, UnlockOSThread is a no-op.
```

Comment: The question links to the documentation for `runtime.LockOSThread()` and `runtime.UnlockOSThread()`.